# Duplicate an object's property names into another without copying values

Tags: javascript

Given an object

```
const firstObject = {
    key1 : 'value1',
    key2 : 'value2'
    // Many more keys here
};
```

I want to create another object like this

```
const secondObject = {
    key1 : false,
    key2 : false
    // Many more keys here same as firstObject
};
```

I know that I can just do `Object.keys()` and iterate over them to add the values, or do a shallow copy and then change the values, but I am looking for a performant solution.

So what will be the most performant way to achieve it, given that the keys are dynamic (not hardcoded anywhere) and we just need the solution for one level deep keys only?

PS: ES6 solutions are fine as well, I am using babel anyway.

Comment: *`Object.keys()` and iterate over them to add the values* Sounds like a fine approach to me

Answer (score 1):

```
  Object.fromEntries( Object.keys(firstObject).map(k => ([k, false])))
```

Wether that is ["more performant"](https://www.google.com/amp/s/ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/amp/) has to be tested.

Comment: @briosheje jup, I link that whenever someone asks about "performance".

Comment: This looks to take the same amount of time as the `Object.keys` iteration method (which I'm a bit surprised at, I'd have thought that the callback + extra array would've made things slower)

Comment: Perhaps a `for..in` could fit better? that would be one of the few cases where `for..in` actually would makes sense.

Comment: @certainPerformance I'd guess that `Object.fromEntries` can be faster than changing an object in a loop (less state transitions on the object)

Comment: https://jsperf.com/for-in-against-object-keys Meh. I know it's irrelevant, it was just to play a bit.

Comment: This looks good, however `Object.fromEntries()` is `es2019` which doesn't work for me (I guess I should have mentioned that I am using Node 10 which still doesn't have this method, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: @noob perhaps you can explain us a bit more what the exact scenario is? If you're caring about an "efficient" way to loop some object keys, then you should exactly explain why you care so much.